# Guess word game in python needs to end

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I end this game? If the whole word is guessed it's over or you loose all life, but I am unable to end it if someone guesses all letters one by one.

```
secret_word = "something".upper()
lifes = u'\u2764'
total_lifes = 5
print("You have 5 lifes in total to guess the answer")
guess = None
for_list = "?"*len(secret_word)
my_list = list(for_list)

def change_user_output(value):
    for j in range(0, len(secret_word)):
        if (value == secret_word[j]):
            my_list[j] = value
    new_user_output = " ".join(my_list)
    print(new_user_output)

while total_lifes > 0:
    print(lifes * total_lifes)
    print("Guess any letter : ")
    guess = input().upper()
    if(guess == secret_word):
        print("WOW that is correct, the secret word is %s"%secret_word)
        break
    if(guess in secret_word):
        print("You guessed it right %s is in SECRET WORD"%guess)
        change_user_output(guess)
    else:
        print("There is no such letter in the SECRET WORD, you loose a life")
        change_user_output(guess)
        total_lifes -= 1

if total_lifes == 0:
    print("You've lost all lifes, GAME OVER FOR YOU")
    print("The SECRET WORD was : %s"%"".join(secret_word))
```

Comment: You should embrace the `'Format my {} things'.format(42)` way of string formatting. You can not enter the letters one by one with 5 tries and more then 5 different characters in your secret word.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `if (guess == secret_word):` will always be `False` since `guess` is a single letter and it gets replaced by a new input every iteration `guess = input().upper()`. So your loop will never quit in case of correct guess, it will quit only when you finish the lives.

Comment: you can input the whole word and it will be correct. nobody forces you to input single characters. The problem is: if you input single characters, it does not see when all are inputted (f.e. for short word 'apple' - input a,p,l,e

Comment: As it is now, your code does not allow to input multiple letters, it doesn't check for any single letter that you have added. If you input `aple` will check `if "aple" in "apple"` which is not.

Comment: It does allow for multiple letters to be inputted, but only does anything useful if the letters inputed exactly match the word,

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell Yes, thanks for the clarification. It was what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You create a set of all letters needed. You add each guessed letter to another set. 
If the set of needed letters is a subset of the guessed letters set, you are done:

```
secret_word = "apple".upper()
lifes = '#'
total_lifes = 5
print("You have 5 lifes in total to guess the answer")
guess = None
for_list = "?"*len(secret_word)
my_list = list(for_list)

characters_needed = set(secret_word)  # set of all letters needed
characters_guessed = set()            # set of guessed letters
len_secret = len(secret_word)

def change_user_output(value):
    for j in range(0, len(secret_word)):
        if (value == secret_word[j]):
            my_list[j] = value
    new_user_output = " ".join(my_list)
    print(new_user_output)

while total_lifes > 0:
    print(lifes * total_lifes)
    print("Guess any letter : ")
    guess = input().upper()

    # check for correct lenghts of input:
    if len(guess) not in (1,len_secret):
        print("1 letter or the whole word! Try again.")
        continue

    if(guess == secret_word):
        print("WOW that is correct, the secret word is {}".format(secret_word))
    elif(len(guess) > 1):
        print("Thats not the SECRET WORD.")
        total_lifes -= 1
        continue

    # if you input a whole word, this will decrease the lives  
    # as no multiletter-input can be in your set of characters
    if(guess in characters_needed): 
        print("You guessed it right {} is in SECRET WORD".format(guess))
        characters_guessed.add(guess)
        change_user_output(guess)
    else:
        print("There is no such letter in the SECRET WORD, you loose a life")
        change_user_output(guess)
        total_lifes -= 1

    if (characters_needed.issubset(characters_guessed)):
        print("You guessed all the characters. The secret word is {}".format(secret_word))
        break

if total_lifes == 0:
    print("You've lost all lifes, GAME OVER FOR YOU")
    print("The SECRET WORD was : %s"%"".join(secret_word))
```

Output (for a,p,l,e):

```
#####
Guess any letter : a
You guessed it right A is in SECRET WORD
A ? ? ? ?
#####
Guess any letter : p
You guessed it right P is in SECRET WORD
A P P ? ?
#####
Guess any letter : l
You guessed it right L is in SECRET WORD
A P P L ?
#####
Guess any letter : e
You guessed it right E is in SECRET WORD
A P P L E
You guessed all the characgters. The secret word is APPLE
```

---

I also added some safeguarding around allowing whole word or 1 character to be inputted.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to check if the guessed letters match those in the secret word:

```
if(guess in secret_word):
    print("You guessed it right %s is in SECRET WORD"%guess)
    change_user_output(guess)

    # New code below here.

    if set(list(secret_word)) == set(my_list):
        print("WOW that is correct, the secret word is %s"%secret_word)
        break
```